# Receiving MSMQ messages on Windows Server 2016

Tags: c#, msmq

I set up a queue on a Windows Server 2016 machine, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to receive messages from it remotely.

`MessageQueue.Receive()` will throw

```
MessageQueueException (0x80004005): Access to Message Queuing system is denied
```

I then configured a queue in the same way on another box with Windows Server 2008 R2, and that queue I could receive from just fine.

So here are some details about my setup, and what I've tried so far.

- I'm using a format name like `FORMATNAME:Direct=OS:machine-name\private$\queue-name`
- `Everyone` and `Anonymous Logon` are granted full rights for the queue
- The firewall on the server is completely disabled
- I unchecked "Disable un-authenticated RPC calls" in the MSMQ security settings

What else should I check? How can I get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Is the queue private or public?

Comment: @GlennFerrie It's a private queue, just as the format name would suggest.

Comment: If it works on one machine and not another, it sounds like a question better suited to ServerFault.com.

Comment: @PaulWilliams Probably true, but: Good luck getting an answer on something like this on ServerFault. Meanwhile, I found the answer - here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work by disabling *Secured Remote Read*:

> To modify this default behavior and allow the Message Queuing server
>   to accept requests from domain computers that do not establish an
>   encrypted channel, add the
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Security\NewRemoteReadServerAllowNoneSecurityClient
>   registry entry (a DWORD) and set it to 1.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms699854.aspx